# Script/Links tags vs AJAX loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to load script tags and link tags. I can do it as follows

```
 <script src="sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link type="text/css" href="sample.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

**(or)**

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'sample.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(data) {}
 });
```

But I want to know which one is the best/secure way[generally].

I think we can handle errors easily with ajax loading or else we have to check onLoad function to find whether scripts are loaded successfully and to find whether links are loaded successfully we need to loop through `document.styleSheets`.

Any suggestions?

My main concern is to find whether scripts & links are loaded successfully and secured way and this is for testing so I don't prefer much code to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Please give higher level problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

As for javascript files:
Javascript has blocking nature. If you going to load multiple external js files on page one by one, consider that each will be loaded and executed. If some error occurs while execution of certain javascript file you can observe it in developer console. Unfortunately, JavaScript
downloads still block downloading of other resources.

> *Conclusion*: place `<link>` tags before `<script>` tags. It’s recommended to place all `<script>` tags as close to the bottom of the
>   `<body>` tag as possible

---

As for `css` files:
To check if certain stylesheet was loaded successfully is a little more in affair. Here is check for existing(not loaded) css file with JQuery:

```
if (!$("link[href='sample.css']").length){
    console.log('error while downloading sample.css');
    $('<link href="sample.css" rel="stylesheet">').appendTo("head");
}
```

To check if certain `css` file was fully loaded, you would probably use `currentStyle` or `window.getComputedStyle` methods in pure Javascript and search for some element with known class or identifier (which is exactly exists in your `css` file)